# taking too much time to get large json data from server using php volley library

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I am developing an app that sync data from PHP server using volley library.I am receiving `json` array response from php. When response is little, it is working perfectly. But problem occurs when `json` is very large. I am using xaamp for sync. It is taking too much time to load the data. Sometimes not getting any data at all. I am preparing statement from `json` array of php and adding it to simple array list.

Am getting logcat error as :

```
36.713ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.657ms
I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 85.126ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 40.203ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 541(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 33(130MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 123MB/139MB, paused 42.528ms total 557.827ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 328.549ms for cause Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.369ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 105(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(11MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 142MB/142MB, paused 7.807ms total 52.573ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.261ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 294.041ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.308ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 388(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 26(103MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 133MB/149MB, paused 40.009ms total 515.759ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.063ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 157(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(11MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 150MB/150MB, paused 7.052ms total 34.742ms
I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 129.556ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 494(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 36(142MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 110MB/126MB, paused 1.517ms total 672.880ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 485.833ms for cause Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.120ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 104(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 138MB/138MB, paused 16.321ms total 38.525ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.983ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 285.230ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.702ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 435(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 27(106MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 127MB/143MB, paused 40.305ms total 493.740ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.107ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 156(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(11MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 145MB/145MB, paused 6.856ms total 25.414ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 413.504ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 56.440ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14(464B) AllocSpace objects, 9(35MB) LOS objects, 12% free, 115MB/131MB, paused 59.022ms total 496.519ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 154(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(11MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 133MB/133MB, paused 5.741ms total 23.296ms
I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 96.541ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 43.589ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 548(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 33(130MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 122MB/138MB, paused 45.755ms total 511.247ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 332.277ms for cause Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.093ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 104(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 150MB/150MB, paused 15.972ms total 51.520ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.796ms
```

My json array is as following link.
http://www.ktronsystem.com/data.json

my android code is

```
        public void m461async(){
        if (!(co.loggedInUserUniqid == "")) {
            jdialog= new ProgressDialog(all.this);
            jdialog.setMessage("m462   Please wait..We are processing your request.");
            jdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            jdialog.setCancelable(false);
            jdialog.show();

            final Cursor mall = co.data_db.rawQuery("select * from mall", null);
            mall.moveToFirst();
            final int mrows = mall.getCount();
            System.out.print(mrows+"    ababababababababqa" );

            for (int idx = 0; idx < mrows; idx++) {
                System.out.print("loop of m462 55555555555555555555555");
                mall.moveToPosition(idx);
                mtempidx = idx;
                final String mfilename = f1.getCol(mall, "filename").toLowerCase().trim();
                String mfilepath = co.getDataPath(cn) + "/";
                final String mfilefullname = mfilepath + mfilename;

                if (new File(mfilefullname).exists()) {
                    StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, murl + "getonlinem461data.php",
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(final String response) {
                                    mjay = mjay + 1;
                                    System.out.println(mjay+ "  m461111111111111111"+response);

                                    class m461prepare extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
                                        @Override
                                        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                                            msuccess=1;
                                            System.out.println(mjay+"  m46211111111111111"+response);
                                            final String mquery="insert into m462 (accode,book,date,vno1,vno2,vno3,part,tot_debit,tot_credit,balance,cl_type,m462index) values ";
                                            String mquery2="";

                                            try {
                                                System.out.print("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");

                                                final SQLiteDatabase mdb1 =SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(co.getDataPath(cn)+"/"+mfilename, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                                                mdb1.execSQL("delete from m462");
                                                mdb1.close();
                                                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                                                final ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
                                                System.out.print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

                                                if (arr.isNull(0)==false) {
                                                    System.out.print("ccccccccccccccccccccccccc");

                                                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                                                        final JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                                                        final String maccode = obj.get("maccode").toString();
                                                        final String mbook = obj.get("mbook").toString();
                                                        final String mdate = obj.get("mdate").toString();
                                                        final String mvno1 = obj.get("mvno1").toString();
                                                        final String mvno2 = obj.get("mvno2").toString();
                                                        final String mvno3 = obj.get("mvno3").toString();
                                                        final String mpart = obj.get("mpart").toString();
                                                        final String mtot_debit = obj.get("mtot_debit").toString();
                                                        final String mtot_credit = obj.get("mtot_credit").toString();
                                                        final String mbalance = obj.get("mbalance").toString();
                                                        final String mcl_type = obj.get("mcl_type").toString();
                                                        final String mm462index = obj.get("mm462index").toString();

                                                        mquery2 = mquery2
                                                                + "('" + f1.abc(maccode) + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mbook + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mdate + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mvno1 + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mvno2 + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mvno3 + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mpart + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mtot_debit + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mtot_credit + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mbalance + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mcl_type + "'," +
                                                                "'" + mm462index + "'),";
                                                    }
                                                    System.out.print("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv");

                                                    String mfinalquery = (mquery.trim() + mquery2.trim());
                                                    mfinalquery = mfinalquery.substring(0, mfinalquery.length() - 1);

                                                    ArrayQuery.add(mfinalquery);
                                                    ArrayFilename.add(mfilefullname);
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            System.out.print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");

                                            return 0;
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Integer a){
                                            System.out.print("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn");

                                            if (mall.isLast()) {
                                                System.out.println("333333333333");
                                                jdialog.dismiss();
//                                                trasync();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    new m461prepare().execute();
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    merror=1;
                                    jdialog.dismiss();
                                    f1.wait_wind("Please check your internet connection", cn);
                                }
                            }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("uniqid_guid", co.loggedInUserUniqid);
                            params.put("filename", mfilename);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(999999999, -1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest,"m462_req");

                }
            }
            mall.close();
        }
        else{
            f1.wait_wind("Please login first !",cn);
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the code you've posted.. I suggest you first look at tutorials of AsyncTask, managing SQLite data and volley..  Like the error states you're trying to do too many things at the same time.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am processing multiple request

Comment: it is working nice with small json data.but problem is when data is large.

Comment: why are you calling async task inside the volley reponse ?

Comment: I want to do:- I have to process multiple requests.

Comment: I am processing **more than 7** requests for different php files.In that some files will have large json array response.When response come I want to create a sql statement and add that statement to simple arraylist.This procedure will work on all request.At last I have 1 async task for inserting data into sqlite db from A Simple Arraylist which has been created by 7 volley request.I will execute request in arraylist.

Comment: you are just adding json data to ArrayQuery.add(mfinalquery); 

I don't  find anything to use async task. You can use directly and volley is almost replacement of asynctask.
although you can use google GSON .
use transaction if you have more record to insert.

Comment: I have used asynctask for I want to execute request one After one .If 1st request completes then it should execute 2nd request and so on.

Comment: are you doing some network request with async task ?

Comment: no I am using Asynctask only for background thread

Comment: If I removed the asynctask from my above code it hangs layout

Comment: so are you dumping data to data base ?

Comment: First I am only preparing sql statement and storing it in ARRAYLIST.Later I will execute all sqlstatment in arraylist using async task.This function is separatee

Comment: dear friend,use progress dialog instead of async task  once you finish with preparing sql query and then dismiss dialog.
or use google Gson lib to parse your data hassle free.

Comment: How can I execute second Volley req if First Has finished

Comment: Can you give me your contact number ? Please

Comment: check my ans below it will work and don't forgot to vote :)

Comment: Wrapped your logcat into code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the length of  file is large, you should run this method on background. try this code :**

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(String  response) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);

            int len = arr.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

               //write your parsing logic here



            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: 2 min I am checking

Comment: I have checked this. But it is being  too slow for creating statement. What should problem?

Comment: whatever time it will required to parse json  it will take .

Comment: It is near about 11 to 12mb

Comment: it would   take that much time don't worry :)

Comment: very very thanaks

Comment: Thanks for helping me !!

Comment: Happy coding :)